# changing background color of UIAlertView , I am getting Warning : No -setContents method found

Tags: iphone

> Warning : No -setContents method
>   found. messages without a matching
>   method signature will be assumed to
>   return 'id' and accept'...' as
>   arguments ....

This crashes my version of it.
Can someone help me to solve it?

code is here :

```
UIAlertView *theAlert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Atention"
   message: @"YOUR MESSAGE HERE", nil)
   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];

[theAlert show];

UILabel *theTitle = [theAlert valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
[theTitle setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

UILabel *theBody = [theAlert valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"];
[theBody setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];    
theImage = [theImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:16 topCapHeight:16];
CGSize theSize = [theAlert frame].size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theSize);    
[theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theSize.width, theSize.height)];    
theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[[theAlert layer] setContents:[theImage CGImage]];
```

Comment: Is this method for changing the background acceptable by Apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

to your file

Comment: Hi, I added #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> to my file,
Still It is showing the following warning.
: passing argument 1 of 'setContents:' from incompatible pointer type.
Help...

Comment: Try typecasting the CGImage to id: [[theAlert layer] setContents:(id)[theImage CGImage]];